# Insert value into tables with constraints

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables which have a binary relation and they are association with each other, how can I insert a value in those table?

```
create table t1 
(
    cola_1 integer constraint t1_cola_1_pk primary key,
    cola_2 integer
);

create table t2 
(
    colb_1 integer constraint t2_colb_1_pk primary key,
    colb_2 integer constraint t2_colb_2_fk references t1(cola_1)
);

alter table t1 
modify cola_2 constraint t1_cola_2_fk references t2(colb_1);
```

How can I insert values into the `t1` table?

Comment: Do inserts into t1 and t2 in the same transaction.

Comment: A circular reference is a bad idea. My guess is that this is an error is the table design

Comment: Even if you sort out your problem using deferred constraints you will have problems in the future. Best solution would be to have one table instead of two.

Comment: @juergend - I disagree. Suppose you have a table "employees" and another "departments". Each employee must be in a department, and each department must have an employee as its manager. It makes perfect sense to have empl_id as PK and dept as FK in the employees table, and dept as PK and mngr_id as FK (pointing to empl_id) in the departments table. How else would you suggest to arrange this?

Comment: @ibre5041 - Same question for you (see my question to juergen). How do you propose to do this in a single table?

Comment: @mathguy the question is. what type of relation you have between t1 and t2? 1:1 or m:n? It look like m:n. So you will have 3 tables. the 3rd in between will also have a column relation type (employee, manager).

Comment: @ibre5041 - I don't think my example is that complicated. But before we go there, you seem to think there is only one relationship between "tables" - which is totally wrong. There are relationships between columns; there may be more than one relationship between two given tables. "employee belongs to department" is n:1 from employees to departments. "department manager is" is 1:1 from departments to employees (pointing, specifically, to the manager's employee id). Where is the third table?

Comment: @ibre5041 - Before we go too far on this tangent - the kind of arrangement I described is exactly the reason constraints can be deferred. Why do you think deferrable constraints are needed in the first place?

Comment: I prefer the Deferred constraint solution for this sort of thing, but just for completeness: another alternative solution that doesn't require a deferred constraint is to initially insert the row with a NULL for `cola_2`, then update the row after inserting the other table. Downside is that with this solution you can't have a NOT NULL constraint on the column.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp  ... or you could defer the NOT NULL constraint   :-)

Comment: @mathguy heh yeah, but then that defeats the purpose of the workaround ... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create [`DEFERRED`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180) constraints, so that they are checked at commit time:

```
SQL> create table t1
  2  (
  3  cola_1 integer constraint t1_cola_1_pk primary key,
  4  cola_2 integer
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> create table t2
  2  (
  3  colb_1 integer constraint t2_colb_1_pk primary key,
  4  colb_2 integer constraint t2_colb_2_fk  references t1(cola_1) INITIALLY DEFERRED
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> alter table t1
  2  modify cola_2 constraint t1_cola_2_fk references t2(colb_1 ) INITIALLY DEFERRED;

Table altered.
```

You can do run your `insert` statements, without having any check:

```
SQL> insert into t2(colb_1, colb_2) values (10, 20);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1(cola_1, cola_2) values (40, 40);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;
commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ALEK.T2_COLB_2_FK) violated - parent key not
found
```

The check is performed when you try `commit`; in this case I have a failure and a `rollback`, because I tried to insert wrong values.
If I insert correct data, even `commit` is ok:

```
SQL> insert into t2(colb_1, colb_2) values (10, 10);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1(cola_1, cola_2) values (10, 10);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

However, if you don't have a strong reason, creating tables recursively referencing may be not such a good idea; probably you can change your DB design to avoid this situation

Answer (score 1):

You need DEFERRED constraint.

See http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Constraints/DeferringConstraintCheckingcheckconstraintwhencommit.htm

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO t1 (cola_1, cola_2) VALUES (0, 2);
```

If you using an oracle db, you should create a sequence for autoincrementing id.

Link: [http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php](http://Sequences)

Comment: This will give an error, due to constraints on the tables